# How to scan for a letter in c++ instead of a number?

Tags: c++

My code prompts the user to input 0 or 1 as an `integer` in answer to one of the questions. I want the user to type Y or N. I tried to create a `char` variable, but I am not getting it right. It says y and n is not declared. I know it's a basic question, but I have just started learning c++.

Here is my code and below that the prompts, inputs, and output as well as a screenshot.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int a; // number of classes held
    int b; // number of classed attended
    int percent;

    cout<<"Number of classes held "<<endl;
    cin>>a;
    cout<<"Number of classes attended "<<endl;
    cin>>b;
    percent = (b*100)/a;

    if (percent>75 && percent<=100) {
        cout<<"Congratulation you are allowed to sit in the examination your attendence is "<<percent<<"%";
    } else if (percent<75) {
        int m;
        cout<<"Do you have any medical cause? (Respond in '1' for yes or '0' for no) "<<endl;
        cin>>m;
        if (m==1) {
            cout<<"You are allwed due to a medical cause your percentage is "<<percent<<"%";
        } else if (m==0) {
            cout<<"You are not allowed to sit in the examination your percentage is "<<percent<<"%";
        } else if (m!=1 && m!=0) {
            cout<<"Invalid Responce";
        }
    } else {
        cout<<"invalid attendence";
    }
    return 0;
}

    cout<<"Number of classes held "<<endl;
    cin>>a;
    cout<<"Number of classes attended "<<endl;
    cin>>b;
    percent = (b*100)/a;

    if (percent>75 && percent<=100) {
        cout<<"Congratulation you are allowed to sit in the examination your attendence is "<<percent<<"%";
    } else if (percent<75) {
        int m;
        cout<<"Do you have any medical cause? (Respond in '1' for yes or '0' for no) "<<endl;
        cin>>m;
        if (m==1) {
            cout<<"You are allwed due to a medical cause your percentage is "<<percent<<"%";
        } else if (m==0) {
            cout<<"You are not allowed to sit in the examination your percentage is "<<percent<<"%";
        } else if (m!=1 && m!=0) {
            cout<<"Invalid Responce";
        }
    } else {
        cout<<"invalid attendence";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output of my code:

```
Number of classes held
100
Number of classes attended
53
Do you have any medical cause? (Respond in '1' for yes or '0' for no)
1
You are allwed due to medical cause your percentage is 53%
```

[screenshot of code and output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chSJq.png)

Comment: Try `'y'` and `'n'`.

Comment: Hey mike should I introduce a     char m; and if(m='y') or if m(=='y') Thanks

Comment: Don't post pictues of text, post text as properly formatted text.

Comment: @UtkarshShrivastava Neither of those, like this `char m;` and `if (m == 'y')`.

Comment: That's some classic code flinging right there.

Comment: Please provide a minimally reproducible example next time - a shorter piece of code people can examine instead of understanding all the (imostly irrelevant) extra logic

Comment: Sidenote: Name your variables so that one can understand them better without having to go to the declaration to read the comment made for that variable. Instead of `int a; // number of classes held` make it `int classes_held;` or similar.

Comment: Are the last 25 lines of your code a typo?  That code won't compile, so it's not the code producing the output you describe.

Comment: sorry sorry everyone I am just a beginner  in programming just learning and also very new to stackoverflow, please forgive me :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `char`:

```cpp
        char m;
        std::cin >> m;
        if (m == 'y')
            // do something
        else if (m == 'n')
            // do something else
```

Comment: @UtkarshShrivastava accept it as the solution please if it answered your question

Answer (score 1):

I think I understood the problem. To do this, you can also include the `string` library with `#include <string>`. So you can enter the "y" and "n" values you want as strings.

I leave a sample code for you.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string answer;
    
    cout << "yes or no=? ";
    cin >> answer;
    
    if(answer == "y")
    {
        cout << "YES!";
    } 
    else if(answer == "n")
    {
        cout << "NO!";
    } 
    else {
        cout << "TRY AGAIN!";
    }
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: While this works, it doesn't quite answer the question. Reading into a `char` does what the author wants - reading into a string does not exactly give the desired behavior.

Comment: It's always good to have an alternative escape route.